# How to measure the similarity of two data

Tags: matlab

I am measuring the similarity of two data with same size is 20. That is

```
A=[0.915450999999999    0.908220499999997   0.900374999999996   0.890547499999996   0.880455499999997   0.868436999999998   0.853787499999999   0.836066499999999   0.815514999999999   0.785924499999999   0.661612000000002   0.208405500000000   0.0495730000000000  0.0148525000000000  0.00604500000000001 0.00292150000000000 0.00150100000000000 0.000730999999999999    0.000431999999999999    0.000222999999999999]
```

and

```
B=[0.915971250000000    0.909765000000000   0.902468749999999   0.894108749999999   0.883719999999998   0.871347499999999   0.857477500000000   0.841131250000000   0.821846250000000   0.796526250000000   0.673128750000000   0.208027500000000   0.0520962500000000  0.0187462500000000  0.00634375000000000 0.00295500000000000 0.00134500000000000 0.000226250000000000    0.000150000000000000    0.000113750000000000]
```

Could you help me to calculate it in matlab? The result shows 1 if they are similar, otherwise, 0 is different.
[image]
Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you show in the graph? What similarity measure to you propose? Why don't you just calculate it? ... Have you every heard of least squares?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution in MATLAB to calculate the distance between vectors is the `pdist` method:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html

It can use several metrics and it is quite well optimized. In the documantation these metrics are described very well.

`pdist` compares all rowvectors with all rowvectors in a matrix and returns all of these distances. For two vectors you have to put them in a matrix and you have to call `pdist` method using this matrix as input argument:

```
% A and B are the vectors of your example
X = [A; B];
D = pdist(X, 'cosine'); % D = 1.0875e-005
```

If you call `pdist` with a matrix with more lines the output will be a vector as well. For example:

```
% A and B are the vectors of your example
X = [A; A; B; B];
D = pdist(X, 'cosine');
% D = 1.0e-004 * [0    0.1087    0.1087    0.1087    0.1087    0.0000]
```

`D(1)` is `A` compared with `A` (1st row with 2nd row).

`D(2)` is `A` compared with `B` (1st row with 3rd row).

`D(3)` is `A` compared with `B` (1st row with 4th row).

`D(4)` is `A` compared with `B` (2nd row with 3rd row).

`D(5)` is `A` compared with `B` (2nd row with 4th row).

`D(6)` is `B` compared with `B` (3rd row with 4th row).

Few years ago we implemented a simulation environment where several vectors inherit from a virtual line-scan camera are compared, and we used this method. It works perfectly.

Comment: Thank Tibor. For vector A and B in my question, How to apply pdist?

Comment: I have answered your question in the solution.

Comment: Well done, didn't realize cosine was in pdist! @john2182 Both this method and mine are going to give you numbers _very_ close to 0  and 1 because the vectors are very similar